# Java Scanner Null Pointer Exception in while (line != null) loop

Tags: java, file-io, nullpointerexception

I try to find how many fender words in my txt file but I get nullPointerException. I m waiting for your helps. Thank you :)

```
public class ScanTxt {

private static BufferedReader buffer;
static int count=0;


public static void main(String...args) throws IOException{
readFile();
}
public static int readFile() throws IOException {
    buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/myfile.txt"));

        StringBuilder strbuild = new StringBuilder();
        String line = bufferr.readLine();

        while (line!=null) {
            strbuild.append(line);
            strbuild.append("\n");
            line = buffer.readLine();
            if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("fender")){
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;


}
```

Comment: Where is the call stack? Can you provide us some debug info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading your line to soon inside the while so it can be `null` in `line.equalsIgnoreCase` (as your while loop stops)

#### Try

```
   while (line!=null) {
        strbuild.append(line);
        strbuild.append("\n");
        if(line.equalsIgnoreCase("fender")){
            count++;
        }
        line = buffer.readLine();
    }
```

Comment: I think the most appropriate way would be to put `.readLine()` only in while  condition. `while((line=buffer.readLine())!=null)`.